# find max value in a list of sets for an element at index 1 of sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this:

```
dummy_list = [(8, 'N'),
 (4, 'Y'),
 (1, 'N'),
 (1, 'Y'),
 (3, 'N'),
 (4, 'Y'),
 (3, 'N'),
 (2, 'Y'),
 (1, 'N'),
 (2, 'Y'),
 (1, 'N')]
```

and would like to get the biggest value in 1st column of the sets inside where value in the 2nd column is `'Y'`.

How do I do this as efficiently as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `max` function with generator expression.

```
>>> dummy_list = [(8, 'N'),
...  (4, 'Y'),
...  (1, 'N'),
...  (1, 'Y'),
...  (3, 'N'),
...  (4, 'Y'),
...  (3, 'N'),
...  (2, 'Y'),
...  (1, 'N'),
...  (2, 'Y'),
...  (1, 'N')]
>>>
>>> max(first for first, second in dummy_list if second == 'Y')
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas for this as the data you have resembles a table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_list, columns = ["Col 1", "Col 2"]) 
val_y = df[df["Col 2"] == "Y"]
max_index = val_y["Col 1"].idxmax()

print(df.loc[max_index, :])
```

First you convert it into a `pandas` dataframe using `pd.DataFrame` and set the column name to `Col 1 and Col 2`.

Then you get all the rows inside the dataframe with `Col 2` values equal to `Y`.

Once you have this data, just select `Col 1` and apply the `idxmax` function on it to get the index of the maximum value for that series.

You can then pass this index inside the `loc` function as the row and `: (every)` as the column to get the whole row.

It can be compressed to two lines in this way,

```
max_index = df[df["Col 2"] == "Y"]["Col 1"].idxmax()
df.loc[max_index, :]
```

Output -

```
Col 1    4
Col 2    Y
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max([i[0] for i in dummy_list if i[1] == 'Y'])
```

Comment: The `[ ] ` are not needed here

Comment: A short explanation might be helpful here as well.

Answer (score 0):

```py
max([i for i in dummy_list if i[1] == 'Y'])

output: (4, 'Y')
```

or

```py
max(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 'Y', dummy_list))

output: (4, 'Y')
```

Comment: Can you explain what `filter` actually does? Is it like `map`?

Answer (score -1):

By passing a callback function to `max` to get a finer search, *no further* iterations are required.

```
y_max = max(dummy_list, key=lambda p: (p[0], 'Y'))[0]
print(y_max)
```

By decoupling the pairs and classify them wrt to the `Y`,`N` values

```
d = {}
for k, v in dummy_list:
    d.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

y_max = max(d['Y'])
```

By a `zip`-decoupling one can use a mask-like approach using `itertools.compress`

```
values, flags = zip(*dummy_list)
y_max = max(it.compress(values, map('Y'.__eq__, flags)))
print(y_max)
```

A basic `for`-loop approach

```
y_max = dummy_list[0][0]
for i, c in dummy_list:
    if c == 'Y':
        y_max = max(y_max, i)
print(y_max)
```

---

EDIT: benchmark results.

Each data list is `shuffle`d before execution and ordered from fastest to slowest. The functions tested are those given by the users and the given identifier (I hope) should make easy to recognize the right one.

Test repeated 100-times with data with 11 terms (original amount of data)

```
max_gen         ms: 8.184e-04
for_loop        ms: 1.033e-03
dict_classifier ms: 1.270e-03
zip_compress    ms: 1.326e-03
max_key         ms: 1.413e-03
max_filter      ms: 1.535e-03
pandas          ms: 7.405e-01
```

Test repeated 100-times with data with 110 terms (10 x more data)

```
max_key         ms: 1.497e-03
zip_compress    ms: 7.703e-03
max_filter      ms: 8.644e-03
for_loop        ms: 9.669e-03
max_gen         ms: 9.842e-03
dict_classifier ms: 1.046e-02
pandas          ms: 7.745e-01
```

Test repeated 100-times with data with 110000 terms (10000 x more data)

```
max_key         ms: 1.418e-03
max_gen         ms: 4.787e+00
max_filter      ms: 8.566e+00
dict_classifier ms: 9.116e+00
zip_compress    ms: 9.801e+00
for_loop        ms: 1.047e+01
pandas          ms: 2.614e+01
```

When increasing the amount of data the "performance classes" change but `max_key` seems to be not affected.